# list grouped files with pattern in a directory

Tags: shell, zsh

Imagine I have the following files/pattern:

- log_A_20000101.log
- ...
- log_A_20200412.log
- ...
- log_B_20000101.log
- ...
- log_B_20200412.log
- ...
- log_C_20000101.log
- ...
- log_C_20200412.log
- ...
- log_D_20000101.log
- ...
- log_D_20200412.log

I want to count how many files there are for a group of these:

- log_A_*.log 1234
- log_B_*.log 3245
- log_C_*.log 2343
- log_D_*.log 6435

Problem is I don't know how many patterns I have as there are so many files, so I don't know if there is A, B, C, D.
How can I find all patterns (and count them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can:

```
ls -1 | sed -En 's/(.*)_[0-9]+.log/\1_*.log/p' | uniq -c
```

pipe your output to `sed` to replace the digits with asterisk and count unique entries

Comment: one liner that works like a charm without extra packages needed thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way, using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to do the counting:

```
find . -name "log_*.log" -print | datamash -s -t_ -g1,2 count 3 | sed 's/_\([^_]*\)$/_*.log \1/'
```

Or using `awk`:

```
find . -name "log_*.log" -print | \
 awk -F_ '{ counts[$1"_"$2]++ }
          END { for (pat in counts) printf "%s_*.log %d\n", pat, counts[pat] }'
```

Comment: thanks it works, but I'll favor the other answer as it does not need datamash to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Using only grep. I am using a "here document" but you can feed the input via pipe. Note that in the example below we are matching just `A`.

```
grep -Pch '(?<=log_)A(?=_[0-9]{8}\.log)' <<-EOF
log_A_20000101.log
log_A_20200412.log
log_B_20000101.log
log_B_20200412.log
log_C_20000101.log
log_C_20200412.log
log_D_20000101.log
log_D_20200412.log
EOF
```

Some explanation:

```
(?<=log_) ............. positive look-behind (just validate)
(?=_[0-9]{8}\.log) .... positive look-ahead
```